# Max of functions are in big O of the sum of their individual big Os

Tags: asymptotics

$\max(f(n), g(n)) = O(f(n) + g(n))$

How do I prove this? Also I'd appreciate the markup being corrected, thanks.

Comment: I've never seen the notation O(f(n),g(n)), what does it mean for you?

Comment: @Yuval Filmus: Thanks, that was an error. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use $\max(f(n),g(n)) \leq f(n) + g(n)$, given that both functions are non-negative.

Comment: Does this still hold now that I've changed the operator used?

Comment: @Matt: Now it's immediate.